Sum rows from a column based on a condition and output them in a new column
In my dataframe I want to sum certain rows in a column and output them in a new column 'UE_more_days'
is
    ATEXT   BEGUZ_UE   UE_more_days
0             11.00            0.0
1     CT      23.00            Nan
2     RT      33.00           46.0
3             15.00            0.0
3             15.00            0.0
4             12.75            0.0
5             19.75            0.0
6             14.75            0.0
7     CT      23.00           29.5
8     CT      24.00           46.0
9     CT      24.00           48.0
10    RT      33.00           48.0
11            15.00            0.0
12
etc

should be
    ATEXT   BEGUZ_UE   UE_more_days
0
1     CT      23.00
2     RT      33.00           56.0
3             15.00
4             12.75
5             19.75
6             14.75
7     CT      23.00
8     CT      24.00
9     CT      24.00
10    RT      33.00          104.0
11            15.00
12
etc

should be 2
    ATEXT   BEGUZ_UE    subtract      add      UE_more_days  is_m_days
0             11.00     *0.00*        *3.92*
1     CT      *23.00*    0.00         0.00
2     RT      *33.00*    0.00         0.00          56.0
3             *15.00*    0.20         0.00                      *74.92*
4             12.75         
5             19.75
6             14.75     *2.00*       *0.00*
7     CT      *23.00*
8     CT      *24.00*
9     CT      *24.00*
10    TT      *33.00*                              104.0
11            *15.00*    0.00         3.57                     *117.00*
12
etc

my last try
bedd2 = [(df['ATEXT'] != ''),]
result2 = [(df.iloc[0:]['BEGUZ_UE'].astype(float).reset_index(drop=True) +
df.iloc[1:]['BEGUZ_UE'].astype(float)).round(decimals=2).shift(1)]
df['min_UE_mehr_Tage'] = np.select(bedd2, result2)

How can I sum rows from a column based on a condition and output them in a new column?

Replace with Nan the values in BEGUZ_UE where ATEXT is equal to "", and after that create groups based on the same condition.
m = df['ATEXT'].eq("")
cond = (~m) & m.shift(-1)
df['UE_more_days'] = (df['BEGUZ_UE'].mask(m)
                      .groupby(m.cumsum()).cumsum()
                      .where(cond)
                     )
tmv = (df[['subtract', 'add']]
       .shift()
       .groupby(m.cumsum())
       .transform('max')
       .eval('add-subtract')
      )


df['m_days'] = (df.groupby(m[::-1].cumsum())['BEGUZ_UE']
                .transform('sum')
                .add(tmv)
                .where(cond)
                .shift()
               )

End result:
   ATEXT  BEGUZ_UE  subtract   add  UE_more_days  m_days
0            11.00       0.0  3.92           NaN     NaN
1     CT     23.00       0.0  0.00           NaN     NaN
2     RT     33.00       0.0  0.00          56.0     NaN
3            15.00       0.2  0.00           NaN   74.92
4            12.75       NaN   NaN           NaN     NaN
5            19.75       NaN   NaN           NaN     NaN
6            14.75       2.0  0.00           NaN     NaN
7     CT     23.00       NaN   NaN           NaN     NaN
8     CT     24.00       NaN   NaN           NaN     NaN
9     CT     24.00       NaN   NaN           NaN     NaN
10    TT     33.00       NaN   NaN         104.0     NaN
11           15.00       0.0  3.57           NaN  117.00

Dataset I used:
data = {'ATEXT': ['', 'CT', 'RT', '', '', '', '', 'CT', 'CT', 'CT', 'TT', ''], 
        'BEGUZ_UE': [11.0, 23.0, 33.0, 15.0, 12.75, 19.75, 14.75, 23.0, 
                     24.0, 24.0, 33.0, 15.0], 
        'subtract': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, 
                     np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.0], 
        'add': [3.92, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, np.nan, np.nan, 0.0, np.nan, np.nan, 
                np.nan, np.nan, 3.57], 
        'UE_more_days': [np.nan, np.nan, 56.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 
                         np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 104.0, np.nan]}


Thank you very much, it works.
One more thing I would like to know:
Line 4:  ... eq('RT') is not the deciding factor but rather
eq('the last element of every group').   (last element can be = 'RT' , 'CT' or other).

I modified the code. It should work now with every value.

my next step is dataframe 'should be 2' :
for each group in 'BEGUZ_UE' :
'is_m_days' = (sum 'BEGUZ_UE' + 'add' - 'subtract')

I modified the code, but I would suggest you open a new post and ask the others for a solution to your problem because I am not that good at pandas. There are better solutions than mine. Copy the dataset I posted in my comment in your new post to make it easier for the others.

df1['target'] = df1['BEGUZ_UE'].where(df1['ATEXT'].isin(['CT', 'RT']))
df1['target'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

df1['group'] = (df1['ATEXT'] == 'RT').shift().fillna(0).cumsum()

df1['target_sum'] = df1.groupby('group')['target'].cumsum()
df1['last_UE_more_days'] = df1['target_sum'].where(df1['ATEXT'] == 'RT')

End result:
   ATEXT  BEGUZ_UE  UE_more_days  target  target_sum  last_UE_more_days
0            11.00           0.0     0.0         0.0                NaN
1     CT     23.00           NaN    23.0        23.0                NaN
2     RT     33.00          46.0    33.0        56.0               56.0
3            15.00           0.0     0.0         0.0                NaN
4            15.00           0.0     0.0         0.0                NaN
5            12.75           0.0     0.0         0.0                NaN
6            19.75           0.0     0.0         0.0                NaN
7            14.75           0.0     0.0         0.0                NaN
8     CT     23.00          29.5    23.0        23.0                NaN
9     CT     24.00          46.0    24.0        47.0                NaN
10    CT     24.00          48.0    24.0        71.0                NaN
11    RT     33.00          48.0    33.0       104.0              104.0
12           15.00           0.0     0.0         0.0                NaN


A task that still needs to be solved:
Add the values ​​from another column to a group (values 'BEGUZ_UE'), one row above (empty in 'ATEXT') and one row under (also empty in 'ATEXT') from a group. I will try to find a solution !!

I was missing something in the resulting dataframe.
Can remove it, but I can't find the pattern.

my next step is dataframe 'should be 2' :
for each group in 'BEGUZ_UE':
'is_m_days' = (sum 'BEGUZ_UE' + 'add' - 'subtract')
